# Magento how to join another table with customer grid

Tags: magento

I want to join another table with customer grid condition will be custom attribute value and table column value.
I have added one custom attributes for customers, attribute name is affiliate_id, and my other table name is aff_accounts, I want to show the aff_accounts table's column in the customer grid.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Here is My Code

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('affiliate_id');
I want to join with another table, condition will affiliate_id = table.column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing any issue you can ask me.Try the below code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addNameToSelect();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
array('e' => 'event'), 'e.customer_id=main_table.entity_id', array('e.status') // added 'e.status' in stead of 'status'
);

$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please find my code 

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()            
            ->addAttributeToSelect('affiliate_id');

Comment: Getting Errors
$collection->getSelect()->join(
array('aff' => 'aff_accounts'), 'aff.aff_id=main_table.affiliate_id', array('aff.aff_username') // added 'e.status' in stead of 'status'
);

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.affiliate_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Any Solutions ?